# PLANTUML : More than 2 associations on class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram, plantuml

I am currently building a `class diagram` on [PlantUML](https://plantuml.com). I have 2 classes having 2 associations class. While adding a third association class, an error message is displayed with `"Cannot have more than 2 associations"`. Is it a limitation of PlantUML? I am pretty sure than a lot of big class diagram may have more than 2 association classes for the same classes.

Here is the error on the online editor: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgAStDuKhEIImkLd3CoKnELQYkXNATyfD072w8iAwk7KY4ImFCrG6nDHNqz1Hy4ukICGIzKXFpyb8nX5sBCfEv75BpKe1s0W00

Anyone?

Comment: Visibly it is possible to add a third association but it refuses a third association-class, and the documentation does not speak about that limitation. What about to use an UML modeler rather than just a drawer ? ;-)

Comment: Well I honestly like the fact that I can "just" code what my project constraints are and don't have to worry about the visual part. I also like having git control for any documentation I am producing (UML with plant, text documentation with markdown, ...). I feel really comfortable having a way of tracking documentation updates, new features etc. Would be happy to hear your thoughts about this as well.

Comment: Using PlantUML ask you duplicate *by hand* all the modifications in your program to have them reflected in your PlantUML diagrams, more the limitations of PlanUML like the one you speak about. Using a modeler will simplify your work, even *only* to make/update your diagrams updating the model from sources thanks to reverse/roundtrip features. Out of that, to have three association-class between a couple of classes is complicated, are you sure it is what you want/need ?

Comment: I got it and agree with it. For me, I gave more importance to the fact that source control is available and that several collaborator can view and edit it in the best way possible. I have tested several UML modeler before (starUML, Modelio, draw.io) and the main flow for me is that you have to share the whole file without any source control and it usually required a heavy software (donut know if it's still the case). I liked draw.io for the collaborative part but I gave up due to so much frustration when moving parts, links etc. Only problem with planter me is the 2 assoc I am talking about.

Comment: "*you have to share the whole file without any source control and it usually required a heavy software*" : depends on the tools. For [BoUML](https://www.bouml.fr/) I use  textual files to save the model to allow version control, and it needs few resources to run (see [benchmarks](https://www.bouml.fr/benchmark.html) even made long time ago).

Comment: Thank you @bruno for the chat I’ll take a look at BoUML to see if it fits my needs.